# Packets not sent with jWebSocketServer embedded into Tomcat after losing connection

Tags: linux, websocket, rabbitmq, tomcat7

We have a WebApp that communicates with a RabbitMQ server to receive messages. This communication happens through jWebSocketServer.
We've integrated jWebSocketServer (last version 1.0 Final - build 50713) in Tomcat 7.0.42 following the instructions at http://jwebsocket.org/documentation/User-Guide/embedding-jwebsocket-server-tomcat-web-applications

In jWebSocket.xml we've added a custom plugin that extends TokenPlugIn and imports a configuration file to communicate with RabbitMQ and creating BaseStream type queues at startup.

**Our problem is handling connection loss**: when we detach the network cable from one client, jWebSocketServer stops to send packets from Rabbit to all the other clients connected to the same stream. When debugging we noticed the BaseStream class suddenly interrupts its "jWebSocket StreamingPlugIn Queue" thread that handles the delivery of packets to all clients.
This happens only on ours Linux environments [versions: CentOS release 6.5, 6.7 and Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)].

We noticed there are some differences between Tomcat versions (the 7.0.55 and the 7.0.69 work correctly) with jWebSocketServer embedded, but only on Windows systems. On Linux it never works.

**There is a Tomcat version which solves this problem on Linux environments?**

Temporarily we solved this problem on both environments using jWebSocketServer externally, but we would have it embedded.

We use java version "1.8.0_65".

Regards,

Roberto